# How in composer.json include 2 different branches of the same repository in different directories?

Tags: php, git, branch, composer-php

Now I have:

```
"user/package": "dev-master",
```

But I want to use 2 branches at the same time:

```
"user/package": "dev-master", # /vendor/user/package
"user/package": "demo", # /vendor/user/demo
```

Is it even possible?
Repository is hosted on Github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot use 2 branches at the same time. This would cause conflicts in both autoloading and building the dependency tree. You can always use only 1 version of 1 package.

Comment: Repository does not use PHP5.3+ namespaces so there shouldn't be conflicts. Also this is not even library but instance of Yii framework app

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that 2 classes can have the same name. The autoloading makes a class map which has 2 files pointing to the same class. This is still a conflict. However, this is something build into composer. You simply can't autoload them together by any means possible. Solution: Make a fork and put that in a different package name. This is not recommended as they expect you to maintain your fork.